# WSO2 ESB - Sending Emails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, wso2-esb

I have a simple e-mail alert use case.

Have done the basic configurations in axis2.xml, and when i try the proxy the following exception shows up.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1420)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)

TID: [-1234] [] [2016-07-27 14:19:30,758] ERROR
{org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender} - Error creating mail message or sending it to the configured server {org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender}

javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1420)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)
```

The issue, I believe is I'm missing the following line of code in the configuration of ESB.

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("aaa", "bbb@0089");
                    }
                });
```

I have tried, tested successfully with a small java email app and javamailAPI including this authentication.

How can I do the same configuration in the `<ESB_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml`

Any suggestions will be very much helpful. ESB 4.9.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to import  the email server certificate to the wso2carbon.jks and client-truststore.jks.

Comment: The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert) has more information.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because the required certificate is not available in the client trust store. Try again after importing it. To import the certificate to the trust store you can refer this [blog](https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/add-a-ca-certificate-to-wso2-truststore/).